# Java Error with Java16 : java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection, java-16

Existing code is working perfectly fine with JDK11 installed. Same lines of code is throwing below error in JDK16

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private static native long[] java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences.WindowsRegOpenKey(long,byte[],int) accessible: module java.prefs does not "opens java.util.prefs" to unnamed module @3f803fae
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
```

When code is migrated from Java8 to Java9, **WinRegistry.java** file is modified with some of the methods' input parameter(s) type from ***int*** to ***long***

Comment: Users of this application are having Java16 installed in their machine and seeing this error. With Java11, the same issue is not observed. Please suggest a way to fix this.

Comment: You should have seen a warning since Java 9 that this will happen. Now it happened.

Comment: It wasn't working "perfectly fine" in 11; it was "barely working" in 11, and there were clear warnings to that effect, both at compile and run time.  And surely, breaking into private fields of other classes should not be something you should count on EVER; that's why they're private.  This was at best a hacky short-term workaround, and the short term is now over.

Comment: You will have to switch to using something like [tag:jna] to access the Windows registry - the `Advapi32Util` class for example

Comment: Or run the `reg` command using `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 for your suggestion. It worked with Advapi32Util class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading/Writing from/to Windows Registry is much simpler with **Advapi32Util.java**

With this JNA APIs one can easily read the Registry Keys, Values and also can set Registry with new key and value.

I used following APIs to fetch Registry value of a key with path to the registry key as below

```
Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, registry_path, value_of)
```

Also, the children key(s) under specific path can be fetched from below API

```
Advapi32Util.registryGetKeys(HKEY root, String keyPath)
```